# Join/Merge Elasticsearch results

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a documents with a (simplified) structure as shown here in Elasticsearch:

```
{ _id: ..., patientId: 4711, text: "blue" } 
{ _id: ..., patientId: 4711, text: "red" }
{ _id: ..., patientId: 4712, text: "blue" } 
{ _id: ..., patientId: 4712, text: "green" } 
{ ... }
```

How can I create a query to find all documents containing the text
`blue` and `red` within the SAME patient.

In the above example I would expect a result set of two documents with `patientId 4711` (contains `blue` and `red`).

Potential solution strategies might be :

- Run two queries and "join" results afterward by application logic.
- Run separate queries based on prior list of patients. Only feasible if number of potential patients are small.

Are there better ways (ideal one query) to handle this use case?

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the way you store data into elastisearch.
Just store one document for one patient id, and keep text as array of all distinct colors assigned to that patient.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [bool query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-bool-query.html) or [bool filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/query-dsl-bool-filter.html)

Example using bool filter

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : { }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "bool" : {


                "Must" : [
                    {
                        "term" : { "text" : "blue" }
                    },
                    {
                        "term" : { "text" : "red" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: misread the requirement:

You should be using [field collapsing](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/top-hits.html)

Comment: Not sure that answers the OP question, as that would only work where the term existed in the same document would it not?

Comment: No, that does unfortunately not work. Challenge is that terms do not exist in the same document.

Comment: I have misread the question hence had updated the answer to check out http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/top-hits.html

Comment: Is there in the meantime with newer Elastic versions a chance to handle such a use-case?

Answer (score 0):

## Answer #1. Collapsing Search Results

As @Prabin Meitei wrote one solution strategy is to use collapsing search results. All you have to do is parse the search results and extract document identifiers and fields

Mapping

```
PUT /patient_text
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "patient_id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "text": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Documents based on original ones

```
PUT /patient_text/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"patient_id": 4711, "text": "blue" } 
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"patient_id": 4711, "text": "red" }
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"patient_id": 4712, "text": "blue" } 
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"patient_id": 4712, "text": "blue" }
{"create":{"_id":5}}
{"patient_id": 4713, "text": "blue" } 
{"create":{"_id":6}}
{"patient_id": 4713, "text": "red" }
{"create":{"_id":7}}
{"patient_id": 4714, "text": "green" } 
{"create":{"_id":8}}
{"patient_id": 4714, "text": "black" }
```

Search query with collapsing results

```
GET /patient_text/_search?filter_path=hits.hits.fields,hits.hits.inner_hits.texts.hits.hits.fields
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "text": [
                "blue",
                "red"
            ]
        }
    },
    "collapse": {
        "field": "patient_id",
        "inner_hits": {
            "name": "texts",
            "fields": [
                "text"
            ],
            "_source": false
        }
    },
    "_source": false
}
```

Response

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "patient_id" : [
                        "4711"
                    ]
                },
                "inner_hits" : {
                    "texts" : {
                        "hits" : {
                            "hits" : [
                                {
                                    "fields" : {
                                        "text" : [
                                            "blue"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "fields" : {
                                        "text" : [
                                            "red"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "patient_id" : [
                        "4712"
                    ]
                },
                "inner_hits" : {
                    "texts" : {
                        "hits" : {
                            "hits" : [
                                {
                                    "fields" : {
                                        "text" : [
                                            "blue"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "fields" : {
                                        "text" : [
                                            "blue"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "patient_id" : [
                        "4713"
                    ]
                },
                "inner_hits" : {
                    "texts" : {
                        "hits" : {
                            "hits" : [
                                {
                                    "fields" : {
                                        "text" : [
                                            "blue"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "fields" : {
                                        "text" : [
                                            "red"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Answer #2. Aggregation

(See Answer #1)

Another solution strategy is aggregation. Aggregation allows you to idenify document and then retrieve their contents with an additional query. However, basket keys already allow you to compose the contents of documents

Mapping (See Answer #1)

Documents (See Answer #1)

Update by query copies the _id metafield into the id document field. It needs for aggregation

```
POST /patient_text/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {
        }
    },
    "script": {
        "source": """
            ctx._source.id = ctx['_id'];
        """
    }
}
```

Aggregation query

```
GET /patient_text/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "text": [
                            "blue",
                            "red"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "per_patient_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "patient_id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "per_text_distinct_values": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "text"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "per_id": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "id"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "text_distinct_values_filter": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "text_distinct_values": "per_text_distinct_values._bucket_count"
                        },
                        "script": "params.text_distinct_values == 2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "per_patient_id" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "4711",
                    "doc_count" : 2,
                    "per_text_distinct_values" : {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                        "buckets" : [
                            {
                                "key" : "blue",
                                "doc_count" : 1,
                                "per_id" : {
                                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                                    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                                    "buckets" : [
                                        {
                                            "key" : "1",
                                            "doc_count" : 1
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "red",
                                "doc_count" : 1,
                                "per_id" : {
                                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                                    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                                    "buckets" : [
                                        {
                                            "key" : "2",
                                            "doc_count" : 1
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key" : "4713",
                    "doc_count" : 2,
                    "per_text_distinct_values" : {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                        "buckets" : [
                            {
                                "key" : "blue",
                                "doc_count" : 1,
                                "per_id" : {
                                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                                    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                                    "buckets" : [
                                        {
                                            "key" : "5",
                                            "doc_count" : 1
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "key" : "red",
                                "doc_count" : 1,
                                "per_id" : {
                                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                                    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                                    "buckets" : [
                                        {
                                            "key" : "6",
                                            "doc_count" : 1
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Documents with id 1, 2, 5, 6 are in the response. Their contents can be recovered with help of bucket keys.